# Ruby on Rails delegate throwing undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a profile model:

```
 # Experience
  has_many :experiences, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, allow_destroy: true
  delegate :incomplete, to: :experiences, prefix: true
```

Experiences Model:

```
  belongs_to :profile
  def incomplete
    true
  end
```

But when I do `@profile.experiences_incomplete` from the controller it gives me this error:

```
undefined method `incomplete' for #< Experience::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000004600938>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot delegate to a a collection. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Iceman I'm gonna check that if three fields in experience are filled or not . i don't want to check other fields-

Comment: @Iceman can you give me link of what you said above

Comment: Well, no link per se, I just tried this on my own project and it gave the same error. Delegate works in ruby on a single object, so it would presumably work on a `has_one :experience`.